# How to stop earlier options of dependent dropdown list from showing up?

Tags: javascript, yii2

I am populating two dependent dropdown lists using an ajax call. The problem is that if I change my selection(master dropdown list) more than once, all the dependent options(the earlier values) show up in the dependent dropdown list. Here's my ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "index.php?r=orders/on-select",
            data: {myVar: myVar},
            success: function (data) {
                var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
                var cluster = jdata.Clusters;
                var sites = jdata.Sites;

                $.each(cluster, function (optionValue, optionLabel) {
                    var option = $('<option value="' + optionLabel + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>');
                    $('[ref="region"]').find('[name="list box element"]').append(option);

                    var opnGrpval = $('<li value="' + optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</li>');
                    $('[ref="region"]').find('.selectBoxInput').find('.dropDownBox').append(opnGrpval);
                });
                $.each(sites, function (optionValue, optionLabel) {
                    var option = $('<option value="' + optionLabel + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>');
                    $('[ref="sites"]').find('[name="list box element"]').append(option);

                    var opnGrpval = $('<li value="' + optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</li>');
                    $('[ref="sites"]').find('.selectBoxInput').find('.dropDownBox').append(opnGrpval);
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You always call append, clean the box before the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `append` to `html` then                 .

```js
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "index.php?r=orders/on-select",
            data: {myVar: myVar},
            success: function (data) {
                var jdata = JSON.parse(data);
                var cluster = jdata.Clusters;
                var sites = jdata.Sites;

                var regionOptions = '';
                var dropdownOptions = ''
                $.each(cluster, function (optionValue, optionLabel) {
                    var option = $('<option value="' + optionLabel + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>');
                    regionOptions += option;

                    var opnGrpval = $('<li value="' + optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</li>');
                    dropdownOptions += opnGrpval;
                });
                    $('[ref="region"]').find('[name="list box element"]').html(listoptions);  $('[ref="region"]').find('.selectBoxInput').find('.dropDownBox').html(dropdownOptions);
                    
                    var sitesOptions = '';
                    var sitesDropdownOptions = '';
                $.each(sites, function (optionValue, optionLabel) {
                    var option = $('<option value="' + optionLabel + '">' + optionLabel + '</option>');
                    sitesOptions += option;

                    var opnGrpval = $('<li value="' + optionValue + '">' + optionLabel + '</li>');
                    sitesDropdownOptions += opnGrpval;
                  
                });
                    $('[ref="sites"]').find('[name="list box element"]').html(sitesOptions);  $('[ref="sites"]').find('.selectBoxInput').find('.dropDownBox').html(sitesDropdownOptions);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! it works but when there are more than 1 option, the dropdown shows only the last one. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think its working but it populates only with 'objects' not the elements.

Comment: Thanks I solved using your edit. Had to tweak it a bit. Upvoted.